# How to grab value after equal sign using python?

Tags: python, parsing, xbmc, kodi

I have a string variable called link that returns data from a remote site.
How i can parse data after equal sign(token=) ?
For example i want to grab "234132421reafdfasdfsdfdsf3234423edfasfdsf" from 
following line.

```
file: "http://www.aaastreams.com/playlist.m3u8?token=234132421reafdfasdfsdfdsf3234423edfasfdsf" 
});
```

python code:

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.somesite.com/test.php')
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)   
link = response.read()
```

sample response value from "print link;":

```
.......rest of response
    <script>

    jwplayer("container").setup({
    width:700,
    height:220,
    primary: "hls",
    title:"streams",
    autostart:true,

    image: "./1.jpg",
    file: "http://www.aaastreams.com/playlist.m3u8?token=234132421reafdfasdfsdfdsf3234423edfasfdsf" 
    });

    jwplayer().onError(function(){
    jwplayer().load({file:"http://www.aaa.com/jwplayer/ads.mp4",image:"http://aaa.com/2.png"});
    jwplayer().play();
    });

    </script>
.......rest of response
```

Comment: `file.split('=')' ?, iterate through the response, get to the file line, and split it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying different solution i came up with easiest way to solve this problem:

```
  tokenValue = re.search('token=(.*)"', link)
  print tokenValue.group(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

A better approach to parsing a URL is to use the [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) module.

Here's an example:

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs

url = "http://www.aaastreams.com/playlist.m3u8?token=234132421reafdfasdfsdfdsf3234423edfasfdsf"
query = urlparse(url).query
params = parse_qs(query)
```

`params` will hold a dictionary with your token, and any other query parameters in the url.

Comment: Thanks for reply . But my Link string is not a url it is a chunk of html code with two "file:.." appearance in the whole link string! is there away to use this information to limit to where to look for token value ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parsing the url any further and assuming there is only one equal sign in the whole string I would suggest doing some string manipulation like this:

```
In [1]: s = "http://www.aaastreams.com/playlist.m3u8?token=234132421reafdfasdfsdfdsf3234423edfasfdsf"
In [2]: s.split('=')[1]
Out[3]: '234132421reafdfasdfsdfdsf3234423edfasfdsf'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . As i posted to end of my post there might be other equal sign in link string so i probably will get wrong value using your approach ! But there is only two file: in the whole string is there away to to use that information to avoid getting wrong value ?

Comment: @user1788736 I think you can give split a 2nd argument, the number of maxoccurances you want.`splitresult = s.split("=",2)` Then do something like `splitresult[1:] if len(splitresult) > 1 else splitresult[1]`

Comment: I used tokenValue = link.split('token=')[1]; and i get the whole string after token= . but i want only the token value ! is there a way to only get token value not the whole link string after token =?

Comment: According to the snippet you provided in your question and my answer the token value should be `234132421reafdfasdfsdfdsf3234423edfasfdsf`, doesn't it? What do you mean by 'token value' and 'whole link string'?

Comment: the code below "sample response value from "print link;":" in my first post  is "s" variable according to your example so i want to get value between token= and first occurrence of double quote !

Comment: So, instead of `234132421reafdfasdfsdfdsf3234423edfasfdsf`you got `234132421reafdfasdfsdfdsf3234423edfasfdsf"`? If so, you can change my input line [2] from `s.split('=')[1]` to `s.split('=')[1][:-1]` in order to select the part until the double-quote only.

Comment: "s" variable is a chunk of html and i want to search for value between token= and first occourence of double quote !(i want :234132421reafdfasdfsdfdsf3234423edfasfdsf not the whole html chunk after token=)

Comment: So, step by step: Were you able to extract the `file` string including your url from your response in order to have this url as a single string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions with capture groups.

A complete explanation of this can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) scroll down to the section labeled "Groups"

"Groups are marked by the '(', ')' metacharacters. '(' and ')' have much the same meaning as they do in mathematical expressions; they group together the expressions contained inside them, and you can repeat the contents of a group with a repeating qualifier, such as *, +, ?, or {m,n}. For example, (ab)* will match zero or more repetitions of ab.

```
>>> p = re.compile('(a(b)c)d')
>>> m = p.match('abcd')
>>> m.group(0)
'abcd'
>>> m.group(1)
'abc'
>>> m.group(2)
'b'
```

So in this case you could use a regular expression like:

```
'^ *[a-z][A-Z] *\=(.*)$
```

Group 0 is the entire match groups 1 and onward match that part of the expression that can appear in multiple parenthesis (group matching) pairs.  These groups can be nested.

Note, this is a general approach and not specific to URLs

Comment: Could you please provide a full answer including a code snippet showing what you suggest in order to improve your answer's quality?

Comment: @Albert, will that do?

Comment: It's a general explanation of regex and not for the given problem of parsing the token out of the url. Please adapt in order to solve the problem of the above question in specific.

Comment: Thanks for replies. So how to use reguler expression to get value of token= and exclude the rest of link string ?(this value=>token=.......")

Comment: @user1788736, you place in parenthesis the part of the value you want to extract, so the regex is specified above could be modified to '^ **([a-z][A-Z]) *=(.*)$'  In this case group 0 is everything, group 1 is the identifier (surrounding blank spaces excluded, also right now the identifier is specified as alphabetic - you can add [0-9] to include numerals and -(dash) and _(underscore) prefix those with \ to be clear you are not using them as metacharacters if you wish as well.  Group 2 is the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the built in string method:

```
str.partition(sep)
```

Split the string at the first occurrence of sep, and return a 3-tuple containing the part before the separator, the separator itself, and the part after the separator. If the separator is not found, return a 3-tuple containing the string itself, followed by two empty strings.

In your case you could use "=" as the separator (sep).  str is the long string with "=" in it.

Comment: use split if you want more than 1 partition, you can pass an `occurances` arg